# Is it correct to say "X is a Y, doing Z"?

Tags: grammaticality, present-participles

Not sure how to best put this in words, but I'll give an example below. This is from a boilerplate text of a company:

> ABC is a manufacturing company, partner*ing* with DEF to...

I would be inclined to rather say "ABC is a manufacturing company *that partners* with DEF to...", or to put a full stop after *company* and then continue in another sentence.

Is there any grammatical guidance on this?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with the original version? "I'm a teacher of English, teaching second grade" sounds fine to me.

Comment: John Lennon was a good song lyricist. But he spoke in a strong Liverpool accent and idiom, notwithstanding his grammar-school education.

Comment: The original connotes that the partnership is important (by implication, to NN's own standing or even viability). oerlikens' look-alike doesn't have this nuance as the second statement is an unremarkable (totally unsurprising) adding of detail to the first. Your second suggestion removes most of the nuance; two sentences would remove it completely, with two separate statements (that are of course still not unrelated).

Comment: The *partnering* version focuses on what ABC is doing (namely, *partnering*). The *that partners* version focuses on the kind of company ABC is (i.e. one that partners with DEF).

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense, although there are better-sounding alternatives, for example:

> ABC, a manufacturing company, is partnering with DEF to...

However, the second example given in the question:

> "ABC is a manufacturing company that **partners** with DEF to..."

would probably make more sense written as:

> "ABC is a manufacturing company that **has partnered with** DEF to..."

Comment: Please add sources for your claims. Otherwise it is just your opinion.

Comment: ... And not wholly mine.